# Why do the value of definite integral calculated by calculator does not match with mine calculations?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I`m trying to solve the folloving definite integral

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{-2a\cos\left(x\right)+a^2+1}$; a > 1

I`ve managed to calculate a value of indefinite integral:

$\int_{}^{}\dfrac{1}{-2a\cos\left(x\right)+a^2+1}$ = $\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\frac{(a+1)\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{(a-1)}\right)}{(a + 1)(a-1)}$

For me, it seems that the value of the definite integral should be 0, because:

$\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\frac{(a+1)\tan\left(\pi\right)}{(a-1)}\right)}{(a + 1)(a-1)}$ - $\dfrac{2\arctan\left(\frac{(a+1)\tan\left(0\right)}{(a-1)}\right)}{(a + 1)(a-1)}$ =

$\dfrac{2\arctan\left(0\right)}{(a + 1)(a-1)}$ - $\dfrac{2\arctan\left(0\right)}{(a + 1)(a-1)}$
= 0 - 0 = 0

But I decided to check my answer using [this](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%20%2F%20%281%20-%202%2Aa%2Acos%28x%29%20%2B%20a%5E2%20&lbound=0&ubound=2pi) calculator, and it showed an absolutely different answer, although we have an absolutely the same indefinite integrals:

Following to this calculator $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{-2a\cos\left(x\right)+a^2+1}$ = $\dfrac{2{\pi}}{a^2-1}$

So now I`m worried about why and how did calculator get this answer, especially considering that this calculator is always (well, maybe almost always) correct

Comment: @Bayesianguy of course $\arctan(\tan(\pi))=\arctan(0)=0$.

Comment: Your antiderivative is undefined for $x=\pi$ so you need to split the integral into two (formally improper) integrals (on $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi,2\pi]$).

Comment: @Bayesianguy it would work if I didn`t have any parameters inside of the arctan argument, but I do

Comment: You are right, my bad

Comment: Yes, exactly, Stinking Bishop, you are right! Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that $-2a\cos(x)+a^2+1\geq(a-1)^2>0,$ so the integral is at least $2\pi/(a-1)^2.$